# In asp.net mvc view using textarea I want to bind the data

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, data-binding, view

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Describe Your Business, Achievement & Vision (Within 500 Words)</label>
    <textarea name="Description" type="text" placeholder="DESCRIBE YOUR BUSINESS, ACHIEVEMENT & VISION WITHIN 500 WORDS" required="" value="@Model.Description"></textarea>
</div>
```

In asp.net mvc view using textarea I want to bind the data. after debugging I am getting the data in `@Model.Description.`.But in front end it is not showing .Just where input `type = text;` those field are binding with data. But the field which are defined as textarea,there no data is coming ,it's just showing only the placeholder. Can  anyone help me to solve the issue??

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the html helper? @Html.TextAreaFor  You should use that and also be sure your data is html escaped and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this.
You can write the code snippet as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Describe Your Business, Achievement & Vision (Within 500 Words)</label>
    <textarea name="Description" type="text" placeholder="DESCRIBE YOUR BUSINESS, ACHIEVEMENT & VISION WITHIN 500 WORDS" required="">@Model.Description</textarea>    
</div>
```

**Note:** The "@Model.Description" should be in between the `<textarea>@Model.Description</textarea>` tags. In your code snippet,`@Model.Description` provided as a `"value"` attribute. This is the reason why the code is not worked for you.

OR Another Solution: using `@Html.TextAreaFor`

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Describe Your Business, Achievement & Vision (Within 500 Words)</label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 150px;" , placeholder="DESCRIBE YOUR BUSINESS, ACHIEVEMENT & VISION WITHIN 500 WORDS", required="" } )
</div>
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Good to hear that it works for you. You can accept the answer then. Thank you for the update.  @Indranilchatterjee